# Possibilidade de aplicação de padrão de projeto

Tags: java, javafx, design-pattern

Após um *login* efetivo na aplicação que estou construindo eu retorno um `boolean[]` com todos os acessos que o usuário possui.

```
// Armazena o controle de acesso do usuário
LoginDAO logindao = new LoginDAO(conexao);
boolean[] acessos = logindao.controleAcesso(codigoUsuario);
```

Agora na hora de aplicar esses acessos, instanciando somente o que pode ser usado, eu tenho um código cheio de `if`s (totalizando 17) que gostaria de retirar ou simplificar, vejam:

```
/**
 * Aplica o controle de acesso às telas do sistema. Criando apenas
 * as necessárias.
 * @param acessos Lista com os acessos
 */
private void aplicarAcessos(boolean[] acessos) {
    if(acessos[0]) {
        tabAcervo = new TabPane();

        ObservableList<Tab> abasAcervo = tabAcervo.getTabs();

        if(acessos[1]) {            
            abasAcervo.add(new TelaMovimentacao().constroi());
        }

        if(acessos[2]) {
            abasAcervo.add(new TelaConsulta().constroi());
        }

        if(acessos[3]) {
            abasAcervo.add(new TelaReserva().constroi());
        }

    }
    // [...]
}
```

Obs.: Todas as Telas obedecem à interface **Tela**:

```
public interface Tela {

    Tab constroi();
}
```

Existe um padrão de projeto que me permita saber qual tela instanciar sem precisar dessa quantidade de `if`s? Ou alguma técnica que me permita simplificar este código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olha, não dá para dizer sem conhecer profundamente o problema, provavelmente mais do que você sabe atualmente. O que pode parecer que serve, depois tem um requisito que não sabia e aí o que dava não dá mais.

Provavelmente está procurando pelo [Abstract Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). veja aí se te atende. Eu acho que ele torna a aplicação tão complexa que até a forma que você está fazendo é mais simples, mas tem seu uso quando a complexidade natural é grande.

Uma das formas pode ser como abaixo, que tem limitações (note que eu criei as telas e uso sob demanda como um *pool*, tem formas diferentes que podem ser melhores que isto, por exemplo a criação pode ser sob demanda economizando memória e permitindo que existe mais de uma instância da mesma classe sem conflitos).

```
import java.util.*;

class Program {
    private static ArrayList<Tela> telas = new ArrayList<Tela>();
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        telas.add(new TelaConsulta());
        telas.add(new TelaReserva());
        for (String item : aplicarAcessos(new boolean[] { true, true })) System.out.println(item);
    }
    private static ArrayList<String> aplicarAcessos(boolean[] acessos) {
        ArrayList<String> abasAcervo = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < acessos.length; i++) if (acessos[i]) abasAcervo.add(telas.get(i).constroi());
        return abasAcervo;
    }
}

interface Tela {
    String constroi();
}

class TelaConsulta implements Tela {
    public String constroi() {
        return "Tela Consulta";
    }
}
class TelaReserva implements Tela {
    public String constroi() {
        return "Tela Reserva";
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7cfxxY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/atbckftc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/Screen.java).

Dá uma olhada em [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Se você deseja que telas possa ser adicionadas sem precisar mudar a lógica do código é possível fazer que as classes que herdam esta interface tenha um método de registro no *array* que seria "global", procure por Service Locator.

Pode usar reflexão e ver todas as classes que implementam esta interface e criar instância para cada uma delas. Teria que pegar primeiro todos os pacotes da aplicação. Fica lento. Pode ter um banco de dados ou arquivo com os nomes que precisam ser instanciados, mas não gosto da ideia, apesar de ficar um pouco mais rápido, nada bom ainda.

Sinceramente dá menos trabalho, é mais performático e mais simples fazer na mão, ainda que não seja a mais elegante.

É possível criar um gerador de código que analisa as classes que implementam a interface e cria o *array* ou `if`s ou `case`s com cada classe.

Se eu lembrar de mais alguma forma que valha passar eu edito aqui. Como eu disse tem inúmeras formas, e só algumas poderão ser interessantes para seu caso.

Comment: A intenção é realmente economizar memória criando sob demanda, eu tenho 4 paineis cada um com 3-4 Telas. A parte mais "pesada" está no constroi(), talvez instanciando tudo e usando constroi só nos necessários?